# Razor-pages ParseExact string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to format this string into a `"MM-dd-yyyy"` I am not sure what I am doing wrong I know its a string that I need to get ParseExact into a date.

> `20210921124857177` is the value and the error I am getting is not in an acceptable format

```
   @{var contentLastModified = @item.GetValue("LastModified").ToString(); 
                    DateTime dateTimeLastModified = DateTime.ParseExact(contentLastModified, "MM-dd-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }

   <div>LastModified : @dateTimeLastModified</div>
```

Comment: You're already inside code with the `@{` - you don't need to "go into code" again with `@item`; `item` will be fine. What's the error you're experiencing?

Comment: What exactly *is* that value that you ate trying to parse?

Comment: Do you have any error?And can you share the value of `contentLastModified`?

Comment: `20210921124857177` is the value. I am getting is not in an acceptable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `20210921124857177` does not match the format `MM-dd-yyyy`.

At a guess, the format you need would be `yyyyMMddHHmmssfff`:

```c#
DateTime dateTimeLastModified = DateTime.ParseExact(contentLastModified, "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

/* Result: 2021-09-21 12:48:57 */
```